# Calculating Balance using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using below query to get balance for a certain customer

```
SELECT  t.[InvoiceID], t.S_Type as Type,
        t.Date, t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance
FROM Statement as t CROSS apply
     (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
      FROM Statement as x
      WHERE (x.date < t.date or
             x.date = t.date 
            ) AND
            x.CustID = t.CustID
     ) b
WHERE t.CustID ='1' and date between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-12'
order by InvoiceID, Type desc, Date
```

out put

```
InvoiceID   Type            Date       Debit    Credit  Balance
3         Sales Invoice     2015-06-09  200.00  0.00    225.00
3         Receipt Voucher   2016-01-04  0.00    200.00  0.00
5         Sales Invoice     2015-06-09  25.00   0.00    225.00
5         Receipt Voucher   2016-01-04  0.00    25.00   0.00
```

as you can see balance values are in correct

is supposed to be

```
InvoiceID   Type                  Date     Debit    Credit  Balance
    3         Sales Invoice     2015-06-09  200.00  0.00    200.00
    3         Receipt Voucher   2016-01-04  0.00    200.00  0.00
    5         Sales Invoice     2015-06-09  25.00   0.00    25.00
    5         Receipt Voucher   2016-01-04  0.00    25.00   0.00
```

update

when i changed x.CustID = t.CustID to x.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID i tried with another customer that has all sales invoices the balance give the same debit values it dose not sum the debit values

out put

```
InvoiceID   Type               Date     Debit   Credit  Balance
1          Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  200.00  0.00    200.00
10         Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  850.00  0.00    850.00
12         Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  20.00   0.00    20.00
59         Sales Invoice    2015-09-03  0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: please give us the sample input data ... they are required to give answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following statement for your correct results:

```
SELECT  t.[InvoiceID], t.S_Type as Type,
        t.Date, t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance
FROM Statement as t CROSS apply
     (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
      FROM Statement as x
      WHERE (x.date < t.date or
             x.date = t.date 
            ) AND
            x.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID 
            AND x.CustID = t.CustID
     ) b
WHERE t.CustID ='1' and date between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-12'
order by InvoiceID, Type desc, Date
```

Comment: thanks but please see the update in question  when i change x.CustID = t.CustID to x.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID

Comment: add both of these conditions together in where

Comment: still have the issue

Answer (score 0):

The results look correct to me. The first row of the results is returning `invoiceId = 3` and the balance column is including the value from `invoiceId=5` which happened on the same day for the same client and therefore should be included. If you only want the values by invoice then change `x.CustID = t.CustID` to `x.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID`

Comment: when i changed x.CustID = t.CustID to  x.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID i tried with another customer that has all sales invoices the balance give the same debit value it dose not sum the debit values

Comment: I think perhaps you are misunderstanding your data and how you are querying it. What is your requirement for the balance column? Are you looking for a running balance for the client at the time of the invoice? If so then your initial results are correct: on the 09/06 the overall balance for the client is 225.00 because both invoices happened on the same day. Same with the 04/01.